# Dynamic anchor tag inside <td>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a `table` and for one of the `<td>` I want to generate the `<a>` tags dynamically using `JavaScript`.

Writing a small snippet of the code.

```
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      @foreach (var item in list)
      {
         <tr>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>  MyFunction(item.Parameter1)   </td> // dynamic anchor tag
         </tr>
      }
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

JavaScript function.

```
MyFunction(Parameter1)
{
    var aTag = "";
    .....
    .....   //some formatting as per needs

    aTag = '<a id="' + someId + '" alt="' + someAlt + '" title="' + someTitle + '" style ="color:Blue;text-decoration:underline;" href="#" onclick="fnAnotherFunction(' + P1 + ',' + P2 + ');">' + NameofTheTag + '</a>';

    return aTag;
}
```

How can the string returning aTag form an `<a>` tag at the `<tr> <td>`..?

Is this possible or is their a better solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.append()` or `.appendTo()`

`$('selectorForTD`).append(MyFunction(item.Parameter1))`

or

```
var anch = MyFunction(item.Parameter1);
anch.appendTo($('selectorForTD');
```

I *think* this is what you're after.

Edit:
Since you're using jQuery, you could create your anchor element like:

```
MyFunction(Parameter1)
{
    // var aTag = "";
    .....
    .....   //some formatting as per needs

    var aTag = $("<a>",{id:someID, alt:someAlt, title:someTitle}).css({ ...cssRules...}).click(function(e)
    {
        fnAnotherFunction(P1,P2);
    });

    return aTag;
}
```

Here's a [quick fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bfbfuojv/) to illustrate.

Comment: so it will append the <a> tag after the <td> tag??

Comment: `element.appendTo(target)` will append the element inside the target passed. So if you pass a jQuery object for a specific td element, it will get added to that td. `target.append(element)` will append the element to the target. It's the same concept just written differently.